# Displaying Posts to profile in groups

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code getting the posts from the database. I call my posts here as snaps.

```
$getuser = mysql_query("SELECT userID FROM user WHERE username= '$user' ");
$get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getuser);
$userID = $get_row['userID'];

$getposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM snaps WHERE userID='$userID' ORDER BY snapID DESC ") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getposts)) {
                    $title = $row['title']; 
                    $date_added = $row['date_added'];
                    $time = $row['time'];
                    $photo = "userdata/user_snaps/".$row['photos'];
```

My html for displaying the snaps is formatted by 3 snaps per row.

```
<!-- Projects Row -->


echo ("
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">

        <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href=''>
        <img src="$photo" class="portrait" alt="Image" />
        </div>

        <h3>
        '$title'</a>
        </h3>
        <p>$content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href=''>
        <img src="$photo" class="portrait" alt="Image" />
        </div>


        <h3>
        '$title'</a>
        </h3>
        <p>'$content'</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="">
        <img src="$photo" class="portrait" alt="Image" />
        </div>

        <h3>
        '$title'</a>
        </h3>
        <p>$content</p>
        </div>
        </div>
");
```

How do I display this in a such a way that there are three posts per row? Just like Instagram.

Comment: What is currently happening?

Comment: Please note that mysql_ functions are considered depreciated and that they are seen as highly risky compared to prepared statements available through the mysqli_ functions and the PDO class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a counter in your while loop.

```
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getposts)) {
    $counter++;
    if($counter  > 3) { //if your counter goes to 4 then it will add a new line in your html
        $counter = 0;
        echo '<div class="row"></div>';
    }
    echo '<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="">
            <img src="$photo" class="portrait" alt="Image" />
            </div>


            <h3>
                $title</a>
            </h3>
            <p>$content</p>
        </div>';
}
```